# What question has the most answers on it?

Tags: discussion, answers, stack-exchange, statistics

Of all the questions on SE, what question has the highest number of answers on it?

Comment: @cocomac Also haven't confirmed with SEDE but Code Golf has a [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world) with 933 non-deleted answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've made [an SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1635981) to find the questions with the most answers per site:

```sql
SELECT AnswerCount, Id, Score, Body, OwnerUserId, Title, Tags FROM Posts WHERE PostTypeId = 1 ORDER BY AnswerCount DESC
```

Unfortunately, SEDE doesn't support querying multiple sites at once, and I'm not manually running that query on every single SE site. Someone at SE might be able to, but I'm not aware of a good way for users to do it.

Regardless, I nominate "[Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges)" on Code Golf Meta with 4018 answers currently.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I took your query and [ran it on every SE site](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1635996/1994536). That should be a complete list of the (undeleted) question with the most most (undeleted) answers on every site (as of the last SEDE backup).

Comment: @HenryEcker I think it's great that you did that. If you post it as an answer, I'd +1 it. Even though you got the same top post, it would be a great answer that I'd +1, especially if you included a brief explanation of the additional SEDE code you used to do all the sites